# Can anybody help me with preg_match? what's wrong with that?

Tags: php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title><?php echo "Homework1_1"?></title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">
<input name ="name" type = "text" placeholder="Type your Name">
<input name = "age" type = "text" placeholder = "Type your age">
<input type = "submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["name"])){
$Name =["name"];
$Age = ["age"];
if(preg_match("[0-10]", $name)){
    echo "Failed, name can not be number";
}
 if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z + ] +/",$ar)){
    echo "Failed, age cannot have letter";
}
if((!preg_match("[0-10]", $Name))&&(!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z + ] +/",$Age))){
    echo "Welcome! Your name is $Name and you are $Age years old";
}   
}
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my program code.
I want if I write number in $Name=["name"] or letter in $Age=["age] the website would show an error message like in the block, but when I run the code and type some values to the both boxes, the website every time shows me

> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_workshop_1_citat\GrundOvningar\homework1_1_post.php
>   on line 18
>
> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_workshop_1_citat\GrundOvningar\homework1_1_post.php
>   on line 21
>
> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_workshop_1_citat\GrundOvningar\homework1_1_post.php
>   on line 26
>
> Warning: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_workshop_1_citat\GrundOvningar\homework1_1_post.php
>   on line 26
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_workshop_1_citat\GrundOvningar\homework1_1_post.php
>   on line 27
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php_workshop_1_citat\GrundOvningar\homework1_1_post.php
>   on line 27
>
> Welcome! Your name is Array, and you are Array years old

What did I do wrong? Maybe I don't need use preg_match? If that is so, what can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Re-read your text book.

Answer (score 3):

PHP variables are case sensitive

```
if(isset($_POST["name"])) {
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $age = $_POST["age"];
  if(preg_match("[0-10]", $name)){
    echo "Failed, name can not be number";
  }
  if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z + ] +/", $age)) {
    echo "Failed, age cannot have letter";
  }
  if((!preg_match("[0-10]", $name)) && (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z + ] +/",$age))) {
    echo "Welcome! Your name is $Name and you are $Age years old";
  }   
}
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but it would appear that the two posted answers identify two different problems, and leave the other problem unsolved.

Comment: You missed `$_POST['name']` and the `preg_match()`es are not correctly formed either.

Comment: need to use    `  $name = $_POST["name"];    $age = $_POST["age"];`

Comment: I didn't even notice that. I just copied and pasted their code with the correct name/age variables. Hah

Comment: Thanks to all! I edited all problems which all of you pointed out except preg_match. What is wrong with preg_match? Should I move away ! ?

Comment: Change your number filtering regex to `/[a-zA-Z+\ ]+`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong

```
$name =["name"];
$age = ["age"];
```

should be

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
```

Also, your preg_match should be:

For numbers:

```
preg_match("/[0-9]/", $name)
```

For letters:

```
preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $age)
```

Comment: Thanks! Now my program does not show any error but when I type numbers in name box, for example 3, the website shows me that my name is 3. The same with age but that is not what I want. They must show error! Do you know how to do with that?

Comment: your preg_match is wrong too, to check numbers use [0-9], and to check letters use [a-zA-Z]

Comment: Which preg_match do you mean? That is my first time I have used preg_match in my code so I don't know what do you mean exactly

Comment: Thanks ! I did not see that you edited your answer. I will test that

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you very much! I got the right result which I wanted!